# How to use refreshAuthorizationStatus function for react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I want to use the function refreshAuthorizationStatus, from [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera)

And I also want there to be a callback if the permission isn't granted. Can anyone help me with this? I havent been able to find an example of how to call this function. I have the following setup for my camera in my react-native project:

```
      <RNCamera
            ref={ref => {
                this.camera = ref;
            }}
            orientation='portrait'
            captureAudio={false}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                title: 'Permission to use camera',
                message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
                title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
                message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
                buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            style={styles.camera}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}></TouchableOpacity>
      </RNCamera>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions granted via:
await `this.camera.refreshAuthorizationStatus()`, `this.camera` being a ref set with.

```
this.camera.refreshAuthorizationStatus().then(() => {
 // 
}).catch((e) =>{
// 
}):
```

Comment: Thanks so much, where do I put this ? And how do I call it?

Comment: You have a function `this.takePicture` onPress right? so when you call it:

```

function takePicture() {
  // check here
this.camera.refreshAuthorizationStatus().then(() => {
 // take picture
}).catch((e) =>{
// ask for permissins or do somthing! 
}):
}

```